# Controller changing date from dd/MM/yyyy to MM/dd/yyyy

Tags: c#, api, datetime, .net-core

I am using .NET Core 3.1 for an API that works like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]ClassA classA)...

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get([FromQuery]ClassB classB)...

public ClassA {
     [JsonProperty("date1")]
     public DateTime date {get;set;}
}

public ClassB{
     [JsonProperty("date2")]
     public DateTime date {get;set;}
}
```

When I send a GET request I am able to get in the format I want (dd/MM/yyyy) because I have a custom ModelBinder that does the trick.

I thought it would work also for POST request but it does not. When I send a date in format (dd/MM/yyyy),  it get as (MM/dd/yyyy) in controller.

I read somewhere that ModelBinder works only for `x-www-form-urlencoded`, but for my POST method I am sending a JSON.

I have tried changing `DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` and `DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture` but it did not work.

I have tried also using a custom JsonConverter but then I would have to add the JsonConverter to every date I have.

I am looking for a more sophisticated solution.

Comment: Be like a grownup - ISO 8601 for the win - https://xkcd.com/1179/.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I am sending the data to a third party API and they request the date as dd/MM/yyyy

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
    public class ClassA
    {
        private DateTime _date
        [JsonProperty("date1")]
        public string date {
            get{ return _date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");}
            set{ _date = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);}
        }
    }
```

Comment: What if I want the time as well?

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings